# How to do logging in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I wan't to know how can logging be performed in Hadoop MapReduce. Currently i am just writing print statement and reading that statement from userlogs directory. Problem with this mechanism is sometime it creates job directory, some time it does not.What is the best method of logging messages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sanjay: A reasonable structure is as follows:

a) write some very high priority only messages to System.stderr.println. These show up in the Job Tracker UI under the StdErr section.

b) write some high (but not v high) priority messages to System.stdout.println. These show up in the Job Tracker UI under the Stdout section.

c) Write your other - possibly more voluminous - output messages in the more prudent log4j method. These show up in the "System logs" section of the JobTracker gui .

Note that all of the above may be found also in the logs directories of the individual TaskTracker machines.